# Working on multiple interdependent projects with Git

Tags: git, workflow, git-submodules, git-worktree

My problem is the following:

I am developing 2 Python packages A and B and B uses A. Thus, when I change something in the package A, I often have to make some small changes in package B to adapt function calls etc.

Both my packages are git repositories. I would like to be able to commit changes from both repos in a single commit. However, I want to keep the ability to commit separately in each repo.

I checked git submodules and git worktree but it doesn't seem to be exactly what I need. Do you know some other method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. A commit is basically a collection of files that live in the objects database, and the commit itself is persisted in that same database, which is located inside of `.git/`. Therefore, one commit from one repository can't contain files from another, so you can't commit to multiple repositories at once.

If you feel the need to change both repositories in a single commit, maybe they should be merged into a single repository (I understand there might be reasons not to do so). Or maybe you should revisit the way one integrates with the other so that a change in one doesn't always trigger a change in the other. Ultimately, it sounds like you're trying to use the wrong tool for the job.